# Validation phase of the transaction flow on a Hyperledger Fabric network (under an assumed scenario)

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Our team is new to Hyperledger Fabric, and has been going through the [official documentation](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3). We are stuck at something where we would really appreciate all the help. The following is our understanding (relevant to the question), followed by the actual question.

---

1. In a simplified sense, as we enter the validation phase of the transaction flow, the Orderer receives a bundle of transactions from the Client Application, they are put together in a block which is then sent across to the committing peers; to perform validation checks, and subsequently update the world state and the blockchain.
2. Further, each peer on the channel, to which this block has been distributed to, processes it independently, though in the exact same way as every other peer on that channel (so that the ledger can be kept consistent)
3. At each peer, every transaction within the block is validated, ensuring that it has been consistently endorsed by all relevant organizations, before it is applied to the ledger. Failed transactions are retained for audit, and not applied to the ledger. Transactions that have been endorsed correctly, are attempted to be applied onto the ledger.
4. This means that the peer blocks are almost exactly the same as the blocks received from the orderer, except for a valid or invalid indicator on each transaction in the block. From here, we followed the [discussion](https://lists.hyperledger.org/g/fabric/topic/what_happens_if_there_is_an/17549879?p=,,,20,0,0,0::recentpostdate%2Fsticky,,,20,2,260,17549879) and gather that no state update occurs for the invalid transactions. They are marked as invalid in the block metadata, and the block is serialized and added to the chain with state updates taking place for the valid transactions.
5. Under all normal circumstances, the expectation is that all the committing peers will return a same outcome (since all of them applied the same processing) for the block, which will then be conveyed to the Client Application.

---

Our questions are:

1. What happens now, if these committing peers, during validation, come up with dissimilar outcomes (like each having their own end result) for the block, all at the same time. How will the ledger/world state be updated then? Are there any set of peer nodes which would be treated with a greater priority than the rest, or would the system maybe go for a consensus based decision? How would such a conflict be resolved?
2. Is it a valid possibility (of such an event occurring - peer nodes going rogue during validation phase) under any set of circumstances? Or there already are checks in the network to prevent this from happening?
3. What could be the possible reasons that might give rise to such a situation if it were to occur? A possible network error resulting in slightly different copies of the same block being sent across to different peers by the Orderer? Or an intentional/malicious tweaking of the validation code that each peer node possesses, which it will then run on each transaction inside of that block? Or maybe something else?

   ---

Thank you so much for your patience of going through our question. We appreciate all the help that you can provide in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I would like to correct first point of your understanding:

In a simplified sense, once the Orderer receives a bundle of transactions from the Client Application, they are put together in a block which is then sent across to the peers for processing; to perform validation checks, and subsequently update the world state and the blockchain.

*Hyperledger fabric works on **execute-order-validate** architecture. Transactions from the client applications are submitted to the endorsing nodes first. Endorsing node executes the proposed transactions and capture read-write sets and send them back to application as responses after signing*. *Application then sends responses as transactions to the ordering service.*

**Answers to your questions:**

1.What happens now if the peers somehow do not arrive at a similar outcome (where different peers come up with their own end result for the block)? Are there any set of peer nodes whose result would be treated with a greater priority than the rest, or would the system maybe go for a consensus based decision? How would such a conflict be resolved?

Ans. Transaction are first endorsed by the endorsing peers and RW sets are sent back to the application after executing and signing. If the application receives sufficient  endorsements as defined in the endorsement policy then the response will be sent for ordering else the transaction will fail in endorsement phase. This is how conflicts are handled. Fabric is able to handle non-deterministic transactions.

2.Is it a valid possibility (of such an event occurring) under any set of circumstances? Or there already are checks in the network to prevent this from happening?

Ans. It is possible in case of malicious nodes, node failure network partitioning etc .

3. What could be the possible reasons that might be give rise to such a situation if it were to occur? A possible network error resulting in slightly different copies of the same block being sent across to different peers? Or an intentional/malicious tweaking of the validation code that each peer node possesses, which it will then run on each transaction inside of that block? Or maybe something else?

Ans. *Possible reasons already mentioned above. After the ordering phase, there's a validation phase. In this phase, transactions are validated by the committing peers according to the endorsement policy and check whether the transaction is still valid for the current world state. Invalid transaction are written to the ledger but not updated in world state where as valid transaction are updated in ledger and world state.*

Comment: Thank you metech11 for your answer. However, I'm afraid I might not have correctly conveyed our question. What we are trying to figure out about (as written in the post) is w.r.t the inside of the validation phase of the transaction flow (where each peer validates every transaction within the block ensuring that it has been consistently endorsed by all relevant organizations, before it is applied to the ledger). What happens when during this phase some peers go rogue?

Comment: I have made some edits to the title and question accordingly. Apologies for the miscommunication.

Comment: In validation phase, consensus is achieved by using PBFT if 2/3 of committing peers approve the transaction then it is accepted and updated in the world state. This is how faults are tolerated.